# Question regarding what graphing algorithim to use

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a school question that I'm not sure what to code with. Lets say you have an undirected and unweighted graph G, which is a city road network. The nodes, n are intersections and m edges as the roads. Among the n nodes, there are h amount of hospitals. The question wants us to find for each node n, the distance from each node to the nearest hospital. Would it be possible to do using BFS or would djikstra be a better choice?

In addition, we would also need to propose a new algorithim that would find K amount of nearest hospitals nearest to each node with K being user input. In this case, is bfs still possible or is djikstra the only solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Dijkstra and BFS is that with Dijkstra the queue is sorted so that closer nodes appear first.

In your case every edge has equal length and so this order comes automatically.

Thus, the algorithms are equal in this case.

> Breadth-first search can be viewed as a special-case of Dijkstra's
> algorithm on unweighted graphs, where the priority queue degenerates
> into a FIFO queue.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting! So I would just have to adapt a form of BFS for the second part as well?

Comment: @TingQiGoh that would be my choice, yes